# Typescript React routes do not work on one server but work on the other server and locally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yii2

I have a few typescript + react components (.tsx) embeded in a Yii2 project. It works fine on my local and a server hosted using cPanel.

However, on an apache server (Ubuntu 16.04, no .htaccess has been additionaly written), which has exactly the same ***package.json & composer.json***, it does not render the Routed components. Here is the sample of the structure of ***index.tsx***.

```
import ScopedCssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/ScopedCssBaseline';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
    <ScopedCssBaseline>
        <Routes basename={"/a/b/"}>
            <Route path="/c">
                <Route path="/d" element={<MyComponent />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </ScopedCssBaseline>
</Router>
```

So when I type http://localhost/.../a/b/c/d. It should render the MyComponent, and it did, locally and on the cPanel server.

What I can be sure is the ***webpack*** works fine and the compiled ***manifest.json*** is catched by Yii2 perfectly, because the **ScopedCssBaseline** component is rendered in the DOM tree.

Here are the snippet of ***package.json*** for all three envs.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.25",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.10.0",
}
"dependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
}
```

I've been banging my head to figure this out. I tried running npm in production mode locally, which still works fine, meaning that ***webpack.config.ts*** is not the killer. The only suspect, I can imagine, is the server setup (cPanel using NginX maybe? I don't have the private key to SSH to the server).

Comment: try adding `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` prop to `Router`

Comment: @HagaiHarari Thanks for the hint! It turned out that I had different directory structure on the Apache server, meaning that I have to do some alterations to the basename.